# How to include a ros-unrelated library with target_link_libraries

Tags: ros, rosmake, target-link-libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want use a library called libnpsauv.a in my package. Although I know that I have to use target_link_libraries i don't know how to use it properly.

I tried:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} npsauv)
```

But then I got that when rosmaking:

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package npsauv_simulation
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "npsauv_simulation" which is not
built by this project.

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Note: I copied the library into the lib package folder.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30532/how-to-include-a-ros-unrelated-library-with-target_link_libraries/) by [ffusion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2057/ffusion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to specify the name of the executable which needs your library as target:

```
 target_link_libraries(my_node npsauv)
```

(In your case CMake complains because there is no target named `${PROJECT_NAME}`.)

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4